# Como concatenar resultadors de un For en Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo el siguiente codigo que me trae 3 respuestas de la siguiente forma en la consola de Javascript:

```
"Prueba 1"
"Prueba 2"
"Prueba 3"
```

Pero yo necesito que me lo muestre junto y no en 3 lineas por separado. Que me lo muestre así en una sola linea:

```
"Prueba 1", "Prueba 2", "Prueba 3"
```

Este es el For con el que traigo los resultados por las 3 lineas por separado:

```
for(let i=0;i<respuesta.output.generic[0].options.length;i++){
var options = respuesta.output.generic[0].options[i].label;
console.log(options);
```

¿Cómo podría hacer para que me salieran esos resultados juntos?

¡Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

si lo que quieres es que te los muestres seguidos **en la consola** (que es donde dices):

```js
    var options = '';
    var ejemplo = {
             options : [1,3,4,'hola',5,'adios']
       };
    for(let i=0;i<ejemplo.options.length;i++){
         options += ejemplo.options[i] +', ';
    }
    console.log(options);
```

Nota: en el ejemplo te he cambiado los atributos de tu variable, ya que no los conozco, pero adaptalo y te servirá

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! ¡Justo lo que necesitaba!

Answer (score 3):

Si la información que quieres iterar se encuentra en un arreglo puedes optar por imprimirlo con el método `toString()` o utilizar el método `join(';')` para indicar el carácter delimitador, por ejemplo:

```js
const array = ['Prueba 1', 'Prueba 2', 'Prueba 3']
console.log(array.toString())

let a = array.join(',')
console.log(a)
```

O puedes almacenarlo todo en una variable e imprimirlo al final de la siguiente manera:

```js
const array = ['Prueba 1', 'Prueba 2', 'Prueba 3']
let result = '';
for(i = 0; i<array.length;i++){
  result += array[i].concat(',');
}
result.substring(0,result.length-1)
console.log(result)
```

#### Referencias

1. [join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/join)
2. [toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/toString)